# Eclipse project move to Android Studio. There is error in minsdk version

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I imported my project from `Eclipse` to `to Android Studio`. When I built project I take error message below:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0] C:\Users\Ahmet\Documents\edx\Android\WonderkidandTransfersforFM17\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\11.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage
```

I tried change minsdk version and I tried add `tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services"` in manifest. I can't solve this problem.

```
 Manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ahmety.wonderkidandtransfersforfm17"
android:versionCode="24"
android:versionName="1.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />



build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ahmety.wonderkidandtransfersforfm17"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/OneSignalSDK.jar')
   }
```

Comment: can you please share the gradle and manifest

Comment: Play Services 10.0.1 is the last version supporting API 9/10. Downgrade your Play Services dependencies to this version or change your minSDK to 14.

Comment: I just added gradle and manifest...

Comment: BladeCoder How I will downgrade. I tried to change minSDK to 14. But it didn't solve. And make another more error also...

Comment: why in first place are you using so low sdk versions? Are you targeting very old devices?

Comment: I did this low sdk for long time ago. I dont know why I choose 10 for this time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a Jar file for OneSignal.

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.5.7'
```

And never use a `+` as a version or compile all the Google Play Services

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Please choose only those that you actually need.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

For example,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
```

---

Regarding the error, you need to change `android:minSdkVersion="10"` to be version 14, as it says.

Comment: I uderstand your suggestions. Thanks... But change minSDK version is not solve problem...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the "minSdkVersion" from 10 to 14 in both "manifest" and "build.gradle". Otherwise you need to downgrade the version of "Google Play Services" library, I won't recommend that. I'll suggest you to just change the "minSdkVersion" from 10 to 14. I won't make difference to your app because I don't think people are still using Android devices of version 10.

Sync your project after changing the "minSdkVersion".

[image]

Comment: Make sure you synced your project after changing the "minSdkVersion" by pressing the sync button on top.

Comment: But if that still doesn't work for you, then give me your code and let me see what I can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a library which requires your `minSdkVersion` in the manifest to be at least 14. What you need to do is to set the `minSdkVersion` to 14 or more.